# simple pivot of columns to rows in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

I have the following table in mysql:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
```

And I want to transorm it into

```
<title1> <title2>
A        1
B        2
C        3
D        4
```

I only found complicated stuff, does anyone know of a simple staright forward function that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'A' as title1, a as title2 from table union all
select 'B' as title1, b as title2 from table union all
select 'C' as title1, c as title2 from table union all
select 'D' as title1, d as title2 from table
```