# How to convert columns to rows in mysql database table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I want to convert all columns data into rows data.

id | division name | student_name1 | student_name2 | student_name3 | student_name4 |
 
1  | blah blah         | abc                  |  XYZ                   | jlm                      | tmn                    |

This table I have created and values are save using array.

I want to save all student name in one column like below:

id | division name | student_name |
 
1  | blah blah        | abc                   |
2  | blah blah        | XYZ                  |
3  | blah blah        | jlm                    |
4  | blah blah        | tmn                   |

Comment: I would suggest looking at using temporary tables, please give a bit more information on what you've tried so far and any issues you've come across?

Comment: Similar questions asked and answered see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: You could look into relating the tables somehow, such as a division table & student table & a relationship table. Then query the relationship table for the student to division match

Comment: @xQbert actually it is the exact opposite

Comment: basically i have only one table of student information with there division using array i saved values in database but it save like first table which i shown in my question so it increase my columns i don't want that i want to save that information only in three like second table which i shown in my question.

Comment: Please show us some relavent code you used. [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) to accomplish this?

Comment: This other answer might help

[Simple Pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078916/simple-pivot-of-columns-to-rows-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

First table into array $students, pseudocode:

```
for($i=2; $i<sizeof($students);$i++) {
  mysql_query("insert into 'newTable' ('division name', 'student name') values ($students[1], students[$i]) "); 
}
```